# Need help about not working javascript (strange div scroll javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

Basically, we have the button "rt50Btn" that every time is pressed should scroll the div "scrollDiv" to right of 50px, but it wont works, i also tryed by copy/paste the element from the demo, but probably im doing something wrong, i need a little help to find what's wrong.

- The website I'm working on : http://animevid-main.webflow.com/
- How it should be : http://www.scripterlative.com/files/vectordiv.htm
- The js we're talking about :

```js
/**** VectorDiv (C)Scripterlative.com
Description
~~~~~~~~~~~
 Provides user-controls for incremental scrolling of div content.
 Info: http://scripterlative.com?vectordiv
 Installation
~~~~~~~~~~~~
 Save this text/file as 'vectordiv.js', and place it in a folder associated with your web pages.
 Insert the following tags in the <head> section of the document to be scrolled:
 <script type='text/javascript' src='vectordiv.js'></script>
 (If vectordiv.js resides in a different folder, include the relative path).js', and place it in a
  folder associated with your web pages.
  Notes: This script does not generate, position or style user controls, that being an HTML/CSS 
 discipline and the sole responsibility of the developer. 
 WE CANNOT PROVIDE SUPPORT FOR LAYOUT ISSUES.
 Examples of recommended controls are <a> <area> <input type='button'> <img> <span>.
  For accessibility reasons, control elements not normally keyboard-selectable like <img> and <span>, must
 be enclosed within an <a> tag with an href parameter set, e.g.: 
  <a href='#'><span id='upButton'> Scroll up </span></a>
  When clicked, links that are used as this script's controls will not navigate.
Configuration
~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   Apply a unique ID attribute to the scrollable div to be controlled.
  Apply a unique ID attribute to each controlling element.
  Each control is configured individually, simply by calling the vectorDiv function with the 
 required parameters. Usage examples are shown below.
   Meaning of Parameters
 ---------------------
 First Parameter:  The ID (in quotes) of the control element.
 Second Parameter: The ID (in quotes) of the scrollable div.
 Third Parameter:  The direction(s) to scroll in quotes.  
   Allowed values: UP DOWN LEFT RIGHT. The last three can be abbreviated DN LT RT repectively. 
   For diagonal scrolling, specify a horizontal and a vertical direction within the same quotes.
    Fourth Parameter (Optional): The amount to scroll each time the control is clicked. This can be specified as:
       An integer representing pixels.
       A quoted percentage between 1 and 100, e.g. "40%". The latter specifies 40
    of the div's full scrollable distance. 
    When % is used, the "V" modifier can be used to specify percentage of visible content height/width, i.e.  "40%V".
         If 'page' is specified, the content scrolls to the next 'page' boundary, where the content is treated as a series of pages, each of height or width as applicable, matching the containing div.
     If the fourth parameter is omitted, the script will scroll the maximum possible distance in the specified direction(s).
 Usage Examples
 --------------  
  All examples configure a button with ID 'scrollBtn' to scroll a div with ID 'scrollDiv'.
  Action: Scroll down to end of div's content:
   <script type='text/javascript'> // Must be placed BELOW all involved elements //
     vectorDiv( 'scrollBtn', 'scrollDiv', "down" ); 
     // Configure any further controls here
    </script>
  Action: Scroll up 100 pixels:
   <script type='text/javascript'> // Must be placed BELOW all involved elements //
     vectorDiv( 'scrollBtn',  'scrollDiv', "up", "100" ); 
     // Configure any further controls here
    </script>
   Action: Scroll down and to the right 20% of respective scroll distance:
   <script type='text/javascript'> // Must be placed BELOW all involved elements //
     vectorDiv( 'scrollBtn',  'scrollDiv', "dn rt", "20%" ); 
    // Configure any further controls here
    </script>
   Action: Scroll down 25% of visible content height:
   <script type='text/javascript'> // Must be placed BELOW all involved elements //
      vectorDiv( 'scrollBtn',  'scrollDiv', "down", "25%V" ); 
      // Configure any further controls here
    </script>
 Action: Scroll down to the next content page boundary:
  <script type='text/javascript'> // Must be placed BELOW all involved elements //
    vectorDiv( 'scrollBtn',  'scrollDiv', "down", "PAGE" ); 
    // Configure any further controls here
  </script>  
 ** DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE **/
 function vectorDiv( ctrlId, divId, vects, disp )
 {
   new VectorDivObj( ctrlId, divId, vects, disp );
 }
/*** Script and instructions available at scripterlative.com?vectordiv ***/
var VectorDivObj = function( ctrlId, divId, vects, disp )  /*12/APR/14*/
  {
    this.ctrl = null;
    this.elem = null;     
    this.xVect = 0;
    this.yVect = 0;
    this.displacement = 0;
    this.percent = 0;
    this.endPoint = null;
    this.useViewPercent = false;
    this.pageJump = false;
    this.useXPage = false;
    this.useYPage = false;
    this.init = function()
    {
      var inst = this, node;
      if( ( this.ctrl = this.$( ctrlId ) ) && ( this.elem = this.$( divId )) && this.getVectors() && this.getDisp() )
      {
        node = this.ctrl;
        while( node && node.nodeName !== 'A' )
          node = node.parentNode;
        if( node )
          this.ctrl = node;
        if( this.pageJump )
        {
          this.useXPage = !!this.xVect;   
          this.useYPage = !!this.yVect;   
        }
        this.ih( this.ctrl, 'click', function( evt ){ inst.go.apply( inst, arguments ); } );
      }
    }
    this.getYTravel = function(){ return this.elem.scrollHeight + ( this.elem.scrollWidth > this.elem.offsetWidth ? 17 : 0 ) - this.elem.offsetHeight ; }
    this.getXTravel = function(){ return this.elem.scrollWidth + ( this.elem.scrollWidth > this.elem.offsetWidth ? 17 : 0 ) - this.elem.offsetWidth; }
    this.go = function( evt )  /** VISIBLE SOURCE DOES NOT MEAN OPEN SOURCE **/
    {
      var inst = this,
          div = this.elem,
          xTravel = this.getXTravel(),
          yTravel = this.getYTravel(),
          xPercent = this.useViewPercent 
                     ? ( this.percent * ( this.elem.offsetWidth / xTravel ) ) 
                     : this.percent,
          yPercent = this.useViewPercent 
                     ? ( this.percent * ( this.elem.offsetHeight / yTravel ) )
                     : this.percent;
      clearInterval( this.elem.divScrollTimer );
      if( this.useXPage )
      {
        this.xTarget = this.xVect < 0 
                       ? Math.max( 0, Math.floor( (div.scrollLeft - 1) / div.offsetWidth ) * div.offsetWidth )
                       : Math.min( ( Math.floor( div.scrollLeft / div.offsetWidth ) + 1 ) * div.offsetWidth, xTravel ); 
      }
      else                           
        this.xTarget = ( this.xVect > 0
                        ? this.displacement
                          ? Math.min( div.scrollLeft + this.displacement, xTravel )
                          : Math.min( div.scrollLeft + xTravel * xPercent, xTravel)
                        : this.xVect < 0
                          ? this.displacement
                            ? Math.max( 0, div.scrollLeft - this.displacement )
                            : Math.max( 0, div.scrollLeft - Math.floor( xTravel * xPercent ) )
                          : div.scrollLeft ) << 0 ;
      if( this.useYPage )
      {
        this.yTarget = this.yVect < 0 
                       ? Math.max( 0, Math.floor( (div.scrollTop - 1) / div.offsetHeight ) * div.offsetHeight )
                       : Math.min( ( Math.floor( div.scrollTop / div.offsetHeight ) + 1 ) * div.offsetHeight, yTravel ); 
      }
      else      
        this.yTarget = ( this.yVect > 0
                         ? this.displacement
                           ? Math.min( div.scrollTop + this.displacement, yTravel )
                           : Math.min( div.scrollTop + yTravel * yPercent, yTravel)
                         : this.yVect < 0
                           ? this.displacement
                             ? Math.max( 0, div.scrollTop - this.displacement )
                             : Math.max( 0, div.scrollTop - Math.floor( yTravel * yPercent ) )
                           : div.scrollTop ) << 0 ;
      this.elem.divScrollTimer = setInterval( function(){ inst.scroll.call( inst ); }, 40 );
      evt.preventDefault ? evt.preventDefault() : evt.returnValue = false;
    }
    this.scroll = function( /*284329323031322053637269707465726C61746976652E636F6D*/ )
    {
      var div = this.elem,
          xAvailTravel = div.scrollWidth - div.scrollLeft - div.offsetWidth,
          yAvailTravel = div.scrollHeight - div.scrollTop - div.offsetHeight,
          xDone = false,
          yDone = false;
      if( this.yTarget !== div.scrollTop )
        div.scrollTop += this.yVect * Math.max( 1, Math.abs( div.scrollTop - this.yTarget ) / 2 );
      else
        yDone = true;
      if( this.xTarget !== div.scrollLeft )
        div.scrollLeft += this.xVect * Math.max( 1, Math.abs( div.scrollLeft - this.xTarget ) / 2 );
      else
        xDone = true;
      if( xDone && yDone )
        clearInterval( div.divScrollTimer );
    }
    this.getVectors = function()
    {
      var vectVals = [ 'up', 'left', 'lt', 'down', 'dn', 'right', 'rt' ],
          tempStr = new String( vects ),
          result = true;
      this.yVect = /\bup\b/i.test( vects ) ? -1 :  /\b(down|dn)\b/i.test( vects ) ? 1 : 0;
      this.xVect = /\b(left|lt)\b/i.test( vects ) ? -1 :  /\b(right|rt)\b/i.test( vects ) ? 1 : 0;
      for( var i = 0, m; ( m = vectVals[ i ] ) ; i++ )
        tempStr = tempStr.replace( new RegExp( "\\b" + m + "\\b", "ig" ), "" );
      if( ( m = tempStr.match( /\S+/ ) ) )
      {
        alert( 'Don\'t understand "' + m + '" as applied to vectors of control "' + ctrlId + '"' );
        result = false;
      }
      return result;
    }
    this.getDisp = function()
    {
      var result = true,
          re = /(\d+)\s*(%?)\s*(V?)/i,
          m = ( typeof disp !== 'undefined' ? disp.toString().match( re ) : [ "100%", "100", '%' ] );
      if( m )
      {
        if( m[ 2 ] == '%' )
        {
          this.percent = Number( m[ 1 ] ) / 100;
          this.useViewPercent = !!m[ 3 ];
          if( this.percent > 1 || this.percent < 0.01 )
          {
            alert( 'Percentage value out of range\n\nMust be 1-100' );
            result = false;
          }
        }
        else
            this.displacement = Number( m[ 1 ] );        
      }
      else
        if( /^\s*page\s*$/i.test( disp ) )
          this.pageJump = true;
        else  
          this.percent = 1;
      if( disp && ( m = disp.toString().replace( /[0-9%V]|page/ig, "").match( /\S+/ ) ) )
      {
        alert( 'Don\'t understand "' + m + '" in displacement parameter for control ' + ctrlId );
        result = false;
      }
      return result;
    }
    this.ih = function( obj, evt, func )
    {
      obj.attachEvent ? obj.attachEvent( 'on'+evt, func ):obj.addEventListener( evt, func, false );
      return func; 
    }
    this.$ = function( id )
    {
      var elem = document.getElementById( id );
      if( !elem || elem.id !== id )
      {
        elem = null;
        alert( 'Element with ID "' + id + '" not found.\n\nScript must be configured at a point BELOW all involved elements.' );
      }
      return elem;
    }
    this.init();
  }
/** End of listing **/
```

Comment: You should really create a jsfiddle or something similar with a very simple version of what you're trying to do. like just the element you're trying to animate and the code that animates it.

Comment: oh, well I didn't thought at this  really :) thanks for the suggest, I'll try and maybe reply later ;)

Comment: cool, looking at your page it's difficult to tell which element you are trying to annimate and what should trigger that annimation

Comment: so here I have the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/L1s194rh/
unfortunately same thing as on the website, I'm quite sure it's me doing something wrong.
Oh, i forgot, I'm trying to animate with the scroll the colorful block, this way i can learn how it works and then i can apply what i learned to the div true div i need to scroll ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jsfiddle you created doesnt have any javascript in it. You have a script tag that attempts to import  `vectordiv.js` but that's it. You have to call the function that applies the `vectorDiv` code to your div. As far as I can tell, you never call this function on your actual page either. Simply including the library (`vectorDiv.js`) will not automatically apply the effects to the elements you want.

At the bottom of your page, just before `</body>`, add the below code

```
<script>
vectorDiv( 'rt50Btn',  'scrollDiv', "right", "50" ); 
</script>
```

Here's a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L1s194rh/2/)

---

**Edit per comment below:**
If you want the div to scroll as long as the user hovers, the makers of `vectorDiv.js` also have a file for that called `slidescroll.js` available at http://scripterlative.com/files/slidescroll.j_s you'll need to import that file

Here is [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L1s194rh/3/) showing how that works, this example is omni directional, with some minor tweaking you can limit the scrollable directions

As before, at the bottom of your page, just before `</body>`, add the below code

```
<script>  
new SlideScroll('omniButton','scrollDiv','all');
//change all to 'left right' to limit to left or right scrolling, 'up down' to limit to up and down, etc...
</script>
```

BTW, when creating a jsFiddle, you cant link to an external file the way you were trying to do. When using jsfiddle, if you want to link to an external js file, you have to do so using the "External Resources" panel on the left, see the below image:

[image]

**note that the way you import `vectorDiv.js` on your actual page is fine, its just different in jsfiddle**

Comment: oh my... I'm really sorry. I'm not very confident with jsfiddle as well as much things, just a little thing if i can, you think it's possible to scroll as long as the button is pressed instead of scrolling of #px every click ?

Comment: Saw it, very good,really. 200% solved ;)